# Puppeteer js return only html header while full html can be seen in chrome's dev tools

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, single-page-application, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer js in my node js application in order to **scrape** a lyrics website, with a url that points to query results (via url query), like so:

https://shironet.mako.co.il/search?q=fire

In this example the query term is "fire".

The problem is that I believe that this website is built with some spa framework, because no matter how I try to fetch the HTML, I get only the header that is filled with some compressed js functions, and empty html body.

When I inspect the page in my devtools, I see normal HTML.

This is the **scraping** code:

```
'use strict'
const pup = require('puppeteer'),
    cherrio = require('cheerio'),
    baseUrl = 'https://shironet.mako.co.il/search?q=';

async function findInitialData(songName){
    if(!songName){
        return 'no song name to scrape'
    }
    console.log(`start findInitialData with songName: ${songName}`)
    
    console.time('initial-scrape')
    pup.launch({
        headless: true
    }).then(
        async browser =>{
            let final = []
            const page = await browser.newPage()
            console.log(`there is a page`)
            
            await page.goto(`${baseUrl}/${songName}`),{waitUntil:'networkidle2'}
            await page.waitFor(10 * 1000);
            const html = await page.content()
            console.log(`html: `,html)
            
            const $ = cherrio.load(html)
            $('a.search_link_name_big').each((index,val)=>{
                console.log(`val: `,val)
                
                let text =  $(value).text().replace(/[\n\t]/gi, '')
                let link = $(value).attr('href')
                if(index%2==1){
                    obj = {}
                    obj["singer"]=text
                    final.push(obj)
                }
                else{
                    obj['link']= link
                    obj['song'] = text
                }
                console.log(`final: `,final)
                browser.close()
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.timeEnd('initial-scrape')
                    return final
                }, 3000);
                
            })
        }
    )
} 

module.exports = {findInitialData}
```

when I use the headless:false option I see in the devtools that the body is empty (and the header is filled with the same functions) and the page is not loading at all.

This is some of the response I get, both in headless and non-headless:

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><script>function i700(){}i700.F20=function (){return typeof i700.O20.p60==='function'?i700.O20.p60.apply(i700.O20,arguments):i700.O20.p60;};i700.X70=function (){return typeof i700.v70.p60==='function'?i700.v70.p60.apply(i700.v70,arguments):i700.v70.p60;};i700.Z20=function (){return typeof i700.O20.P20==='function'?i700.O20.P20.apply(i700.O20,arguments):i700.O20.P20;};i700.Q60=function (){return typeof i700.Y60.P20==='function'?
...
;winsocks();</script></head><body></body></html>
```

Some of the HTML shown in the devtools:

```
    <tbody><tr>
        <td class="global_main_shadow" align="center">
            <table width="1020" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td width="20" valign="top" align="left">
        
                <img src="/jsp/images/global_bg_right.gif" width="20" height="556"></td>
...


</tbody>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Because without any body the cheerio part fails, and the function doesn't works.

I saw some answers regrading similar issues here and in google, but for them page.waitFor and adding waitUntil networkidle2 solved it, but not for me.

EDIT:

I tried to send requests for the same URL using tools like axios and insomnia, and they got the empty body response.

When I used postman though, I got the correct HTML.

What postman does right that any other tools is doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can the `node-fetch` module to fetch it. The page is server side-rendered. So don't need to use puppeteer.

Comment: @NguyenHoang: I used axios to try to get the data and got empty body. Just to check I used node-fetch, and got the same results.

Comment: It work on my machine. I provide the code and the screenshot below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

(async () => {
  const url = "https://shironet.mako.co.il/search?q=fire";
  const result = await fetch(url);
  const response = await result.text();
  console.log(response);
})();
```

It worked on my machine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure you are getting a body? I tried your code on my machine and I still get empty html body

Comment: Yes, full body. You can try it again. At the first time, it don't work. But after few times, it work correctly.

Comment: I don't know what is going wrong, but I try your solution in my mint machine and it doesn't work, no matter how many times I try